# Compare missing values in python pandas from another column

Tags: python, pandas, compare, missing-data

I have a pandas data frame that consists of two columns with value. Some of the values are missing and I would like to create a third column that marks if there are missing values in both columns or if one is filled. I am unsure on how to do this since I am new any help you can provided would be greatly appreciated

```
#input 
df = {'First': ['','','A','B','B','C'], 
  'Second': ['12', '', '10', '', '', '11']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)

#Possible output of third column
df['Third'] = ['Secondfilled', 'missing', 'bothfilled', 'Firstfilled', 'Firstfilled', bothfilled']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apply()` with a lookup dict.

```py
lookup = {'10': 'Firstfilled', '01': 'Secondfilled', '11': 'bothfilled', '00': 'missing'}

def fill(row):
    key = '00'

    if row['First'] != '':
        key = '1' + key[1]

    if row['Second'] != '':
        key = key[0] + '1'

    return lookup[key]

df['Third'] = df.apply(fill, axis=1)
```

```
# print(df)

  First Second         Third
0           12  Secondfilled
1                    missing
2     A     10    bothfilled
3     B          Firstfilled
4     B          Firstfilled
5     C     11    bothfilled
```

Answer (score 3):

One-line solution with no ifelse nor custom functions.
Improved with @SeaBean 's suggestion!

```py
d = {0: 'Missing', 1: 'FirstFilled', 2: 'SecondFilled', 3: 'BothFilled'}
df['Third'] = (df.ne('')*(1,2)).sum(1).map(d)
```

Output:

```py
print(df)

  First Second         Third
0           12  SecondFilled
1                    Missing
2     A     10    BothFilled
3     B          FirstFilled
4     B          FirstFilled
5     C     11    BothFilled
```

Comment: Upvoted. Can also do `.sum(1)`to replace `.apply(sum, axis = 1)` to further simplify it.

Comment: Great idea! Thanks